# Uncertainty on the sum of two non-commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

Suppose that I have an observable
$$
\hat{E} = \sin(\alpha) \hat{Q} + \cos({\alpha}) \hat{P}
$$

with $\hat{Q}, \hat{P}$ being non-commuting operators satisfying

$$
[\hat{Q}, \hat{P}] = i \hbar
$$

It is clear that $\langle E \rangle$ could be $0$ or less than $0$, but since both operators do not commute, I guess that that $\langle E^2 \rangle \geq C$ with $C \geq 0$. However I failed to find a lower bound of it for any $\alpha$. Can someone give me a lower bound for C in function of $\alpha$?

Comment: The spectrum of your operator $E$ (its unique selfadjoint extension on the Schwartz space) is continuous and coincides with $\mathbb{R}$, so the one of $E^2$ is $[0,+\infty)$  and there is no $C>0$ satisfying your request...  However without a rigorous  discussion on domains it is not possible to achieve any sensible conclusion.  This is a mathematical problem, so that physical intuition is not sufficient...

Comment: You are right, I edited the $>$ in $\geq$ signs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of giving a rigorous argument based on the representation of Heisenberg-Weyl group, I suggest a physically minded argument which could be made rigorous however. (I henceforth assume $\hbar=1$)

Consider the Hamiltonian $H= \frac{1}{2m}P^2$. We know that the Heisenberg evolution of the position operator under this free evolution is
$$e^{i \frac{t}{2m} P^2} X e^{-i \frac{t}{2m} P^2} = X+ \frac{t}{m}P\:.$$
Therefore, for $\frac{t}{m} = \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}$ with $\sin \alpha \neq 0$ (I will discuss this case later)
$$e^{i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2} X e^{-i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2} = X+ \frac{\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}P\:.$$
so that
$$ (\sin \alpha) X + (\cos \alpha) P  = (\sin \alpha)
 e^{i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2} X e^{-i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2}\:.$$
Since $ e^{i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2}$ is unitary, the operator
$$ e^{i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2} X e^{-i \frac{\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha} P^2}$$ is selfadjoint because $X$ is and it
has exactly the same spectrum as $X$ (same type of spectrum and same degeneracy): continuous spectrum which coincides with  $\mathbb{R}$ without degeneracy.
Multiplying a self-adjoint operator  with a real constant  does not affect self-adjointeness, it  just changes the spectrum by the same multiplicative factor.
We conclude that, for $\sin\alpha \neq 0$,
$$ E= (\sin \alpha) X + (\cos \alpha) P $$
has continuous spectrum which coincides with  $\mathbb{R}$ without degeneracy.

The spectrum of $E^2$ is therefore still continuous and it amounts to $[0,\infty)$.

In particular, its spectral decomposition has the form
$$E^2 = \int_{[0,+\infty)} \lambda dP(\lambda)\:.$$
For every given $\epsilon>0$, we can choose a non-vanishing vector satisfying $\psi = P_{[0,\epsilon)} \psi$ (notice that this is possible just because the spectrum completely fills $[0,+\infty)$.
We can also assume that $||\psi||^2 =1$. Therefore
$$\langle E^2\rangle_\psi= \langle \psi|E^2 \psi \rangle = \int_0^\epsilon \lambda d\langle \psi|P(\lambda) \psi\rangle \leq \epsilon \int_0^\epsilon  d\langle \psi|P(\lambda) \psi\rangle  = \epsilon \langle \psi|\psi\rangle = \epsilon.$$

*We conclude that there is no chance to find a strictly positively bound below (the constant $C>0$) the expectation value of $E^2$.*

If $\sin \alpha=0$, then the considered operator boils down to $P$ and we find again the same features as above.

**REMARK**. I just realized this fact. Using the Hamiltonian $$H=\frac{1}{2m}P^2+\frac{k}{2}X^2$$ one directly obtains
$$e^{itH} X e^{-itH} = \cos (\omega t) X + \sin (\omega t) P$$
with $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, making the discussion even easier, defining $\alpha = \omega t + \pi/2$. I think this was the spirit of the exercise....I do not want to re-write the discussion above accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

It does not matter that $Q$ and $P$ do not commute, if they are self-adjoint, so is your $E$, and the square of a self-adjoint operator is a non-negative operator:

$$\langle \psi \vert E^2 \vert \psi\rangle = \langle \psi \vert E^\dagger E\vert \psi\rangle = \lvert\lvert E\lvert \psi\rangle\rvert\rvert^2 \geq 0 $$

Equality $\langle E^2\rangle = 0$ happens if and only if $\lvert \psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $E$ with eigenvalue 0 (or if $\lvert \psi\rangle$ is the zero vector).

Comment: Actually there are no proper eigenvectors of $E$: its unique selfadjoint extension  on, for example, the Schwartz space, has continuous spectrum $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! You made me realise that my question was not well formulated. I forgot to ask for the lower bound of C. I upvote your answer, but I actually edited my question, so your question does not answer it anymore...

Comment: @NicolasSchmid Please don't edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. It can of course happen that an answer makes you realize the question you wrote wasn't the question you wanted to ask, but in that case, please just ask the question you actually wanted to ask as a new separate question instead of editing this one.